# Convert Unix Timestamp to human format in Django with Python

Tags: python, django, string, datetime, formatting

I'd like to a convert unix timestamp I have in a string (ex. 1277722499.82) into a more humanized format (hh:mm:ss or similar).  Is there an easy way to do this in python for a django app?  This is outside of a template, in the model that I would like to do this. Thanks.

**edit**
I'm using the python function time.time() to generate the timestamp.  According to the doc:

> time.time()
>
> Return the time as a floating point number expressed in seconds
> since the epoch, in UTC. Note that
> even though the time is always
> returned as a floating point number,
> not all systems provide time with a
> better precision than 1 second. While
> this function normally returns
> non-decreasing values, it can return a
> lower value than a previous call if
> the system clock has been set back
> between the two calls.

Comment: The decimal places in your example look a bit odd - Unix timestamp is usually an integer count of seconds since 1-Jan-1970 isn't it?

Comment: @joefis: the fractional part means (or should mean) the fraction of the second.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```py
import datetime
datestring = "1277722499.82"

dt = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(datestring))
print(dt)
2010-06-28 11:54:59.820000
```

Comment: Or presumably, if you're working with timezones, `.utcfromtimestamp()`.