# convert unix time to mysql datetime and include milliseconds

Tags: python, mysql

```
timestamp  = 1539965545566873
timestamp = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.{:03d}')
ValueError: year is out of range
```

I this include microseconds and milliseconds. So I can divide it by /1000 to lose the accuracy of microseconds, but I want to store milliseconds too.

Any idea how? Also, I'm using Django, if that matters.

Comment: See this: [Convert Unix Timestamp to human format in Django with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3133486)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Unix Timestamp to human format in Django with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3133486/convert-unix-timestamp-to-human-format-in-django-with-python)

Comment: @Nick it wasn't labelled microseconds or searchable for it

Comment: No argument there. I don't know how @rask004 found it...

Comment: @Nick googling "Django Unix timestamp convert datetime stackoverflow"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick workaround:

```
timestamp = 1539965545566873
time, micro = divmod(timestamp, 1000000)
timestamp = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(time).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.')
timestamp += str(micro)

timestamp
>>>'2018-10-19 16:12:25.566873'
```

AFAIK `utcfromtimestamp` does not have a parameter that allows you to pass in microseconds.

Comment: Is divmod a library?

Comment: It's a python built-in function like `str`, `list`, `len`. description: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod